# How to dynamically preset/select the value of a html select object using Django?

Tags: django

This is the html file

```
        <label for="caller">Caller</label>
        <select name="caller">
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
        </select>
```

I want to **dynamically** preset the value of the *caller*. How can I do that?

E.G sometimes I want it to be 20, sometimes it can be 22. The value I want to send is stored in a variable and available as *{{caller}}*

Comment: Assuming this is a form element, you should just use a django form with initial values (or at least show what you've tried..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `caller` from `view` function to template and you are trying to show default selected value then use `selected="selected"`

```
<option {% if caller == "20" %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>20</option>
```